# Lucene search (How to query?)

Tags: lucene

I am trying to use Lucene full text search. And I cannot understand how to index/search using word forms. First of all I do not wanna to write all by my self. If I use StandardAnalyzer with QueryParser I can find the text like:

> some testing text

by queries like "test~", "testing", but it is not works if I try to find it by query like "tested".

So please tell me how to make it right;)))

Thank you for any advice!!!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use luke for testing queries etc: 
http://www.getopt.org/luke/

It will rewrite and decomponse your query so you can debug the situation.